# Ubuntu 16.04 - timezone changing to Los Angeles time automatically

Tags: 16.04, time, timezone

Every now and then, usually some time at night the system time in Ubuntu 16.04 changes to Los Angeles time. I live in the UK and it is normally set to London. My HP Pavilion DV6 laptop did not restart during this time. Is there a way to find out what causes this and how to correct? It's not a dual boot setup, so it can't be Windows.

Comment: No idea, but yeah, very interesting.

Comment: What's the output of `date`? Specifically, what timezone does it show?

Comment: @terdon `date` shows - `Tue 21 Mar 18:08:02 GMT 2017`

Answer (score 3):

Check current timezone settings by opening a terminal and executing : `timedatectl status`

```
$ timedatectl status
      Local time: Di 2017-03-21 14:32:44 CET
  Universal time: Di 2017-03-21 13:32:44 UTC
        RTC time: Di 2017-03-21 13:32:44
       Time zone: Europe/Berlin (CET, +0100)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Important is that `RTC in local TZ` is set to `no` - change the timezone settings by executing :

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 0  
timedatectl set-ntp true
timedatectl set-timezone Europe/London
```

Make sure that `Network time on` and `NTP synchronized` are set to `yes` -
 reboot the system.
Enter the BIOS ... check (modify in case they are wrong) time settings there - then boot Ubuntu.

Check whether the time synchronization service is running with : `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service`. For reference and more comprehensive information -> `man timedatectl`

Comment: `timedatectl status` showed everything was as described above. Didn't need to set anything. BIOS was set to correct time. `systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service` showed `Active: active (running)`.